# Initilazing list in kotlin without null and add element to it.Avoiding tradition loop and defining length of list to loop over

Tags: list, for-loop, kotlin, stream

This way is creating list of list

```
fun searchByTaskNProcessKey(@RequestBody search: TaskSearch): Any? {
    var config: List<Any?> = listOf(addConfig(search.processKeys!![0],search.taskNames!![0]))
    for(i in  1 until (search.taskNames?.size!!)){
        config+= addConfig(search.processKeys!![i],search.taskNames!![i])
    }
    return config
}
```

RequestBody is json:

```
{"taskNames": ["task1","Task2"],
"processKeys": ["key1","key2"]}
```

Based on the processKey and taskName i am tring to add ProcessVariable class to config List.
I have tried few things like  `var config:List<ProcessVariable>=toArrayList()`and `var config: List<ProcessVariable>? =null`
but this makes list immutable and i cannot add new element I tried MutableList but It was also throwing error.And type List cannot be converted to arraylist.Is there a better way to intialise List and then add elecment to it or without using traditional loop using kotlin shorthand according to taskName and key assuming task1 and key1 and respective are correct pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun searchByTaskNProcessKey(@RequestBody search: TaskSearch) = 
    search.processKeys!!.zip(search.taskNames!!, ::addConfig)
```

The returned list has length of the shortest collection